# AngularJS 1 foreach non annoymous function

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to define the iterator function for an `angular.forEach` call so that you can use the iterator function in different contexts and such.
This is the normal way you use `angular.forEach`:

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  ...
});
```

I'm looking for something like this

```
function doSomething(value,key){
    ...
}

angular.forEach(values, doSomething(value,key));
```

Can you only do cross controller function using services? Can these functions be used for the iterator function in angular.forEach? And how do you pass arguments into the iterator function?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
angular.forEach(values, doSomething);
```

Angular will pass the key and value to the function for each `value` in `values`.

Comment: How do you pass additional variables into the doSomething function?

Comment: I need to pass in $http